# Is there a solution to find x?

Tags: geometry

[image]

$$DE//AB$$
$$m(ACF) = m(FCB) =m(DEC)$$
Here is a question which fixed with my teacher. So I didn't understand which my teacher used way to fix it. In my view, there is no solution to fix it.

Comment: $\angle ACB$ looks like a smiley face

Comment: Yes, agree with you.

Comment: Are the angle $\angle ACF$ , $\angle FCB$ and $\angle DEC$ all equal ? The triangle $CE$ and the central point does not look very isosceles ... $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Yes the are equal

Comment: Yes indeed you are correct. We can slide DE or AB up or down.

Comment: Can none solve this?

Comment: @Bobtrollsten See my answer below.  This problem has no solution because the value of $x$ is not determined by the given information.

Comment: $m(ACF) = m(FCB) =m(DEC)$

Comment: Can I get help now?

Comment: I am not sure what additional help you expect.  The value of x is not determined by the given information

Comment: AED is equilateral.

Comment: Do you mean AFD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without additional information, no, the given information does not determine the measure of $\angle DFC$.  You can see this by imagining segment $DE$ sliding downward, remaining parallel to $AB$ as it goes.  As $DE$ gets closer to $AB$, all of the givens of the problem remain satisfied, but the measure of $x$ would steadily increase.

**EDITED:**  With the additional information that $AFD$ is equilateral, the problem becomes solvable.  We know that $m\angle DAF = 60$; since $DE$ is parallel to $AB$, we also have $m\angle CDE = 60$.  Now let $z$ denote the measure of $\angle ACF, \angle FCB$ and $\angle DEC$.  Since the sum of the measures in triangle $CDE$ must be $180$, we have $60 + 3z = 180$, whence $z = 40$.

Now look at triangle $CDF$.  We know that $m\angle DCF = 40$.  We also know that $m\angle CDF = 120$, because that angle is supplementary to $\angle ADF$, which is 60 degrees.  From this, it follows that $x = 20$.

Comment: $m(ACF) = m(FCB) =m(DEC)$ is there a solution now?

Comment: Also the answer is $20$

Comment: No, the information that those three angles does not constrain the solution.  $x$ *does not* have to be 20.

Comment: AED is equilateral

Comment: @Bobtrollsten That missing piece of information changes the entire problem.  Please edit your original question to include it.